# Animation on custom infowindow using google maps in Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, animation, google-api

I'm trying to use customized marker "bubbles" in my Android app. To do this, I created a InfoWindowAdapter which returns and populates the View.

However, for some reason, it seems it won't let me apply an animation to that view (or whatever is inside). I would like it to pop in a certain, animated way but I'm probably missing something.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {
    private final View contents = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.marker_layout, null);

    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        TranslateAnimation animator = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f);

        animator.setDuration(2000);
        animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        animator.setFillAfter(true);

        contents.findViewById(R.id.entity_name).clearAnimation();
        contents.findViewById(R.id.entity_name).startAnimation(animator);

        ((TextView) contents.findViewById(R.id.entity_name)).setText(marker.getTitle());
        return contents;
    }
/* ... */
```

The view gets succesfully created and populated, but no aparent animation. If I apply that same animation to another element of the layout it works flawlessly so I'm starting to think this is something about the way Google Maps uses the information windows, perhaps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't apply animation to the `InfoWindow`, for one simple reason. what you see in the `InfoWindow` is not the layout you defined but an image that was drawn from it. meaning you can'y manipulate this `InfoWindow`.

From Google's documentation:

> **Note:** The info window that is drawn is not a live view. The view is rendered as an image (using `View.draw(Canvas)`) at the time it is returned. This means that any subsequent changes to the view will not be reflected by the info window on the map. To update the info window later (e.g., after an image has loaded), call `showInfoWindow()`. Furthermore, the info window will not respect any of the interactivity typical for a normal view such as touch or gesture events. However you can listen to a generic click event on the whole info window as described in the section below.

Comment: But, I have checked Uber application, and it uses the animation in InfoWindow. How it does that, if we can't apply animation to the InfoWindow?

Answer (score 3):

You may try to work this limitation around by using `Handler` and `Marker.showInfoWindow()`.

For a short period of time, send messages to handler, call showInfoWindow and create different views (with different bottom margin in your case) every time in getInfoWindow.

This can be a bit tricky. You will have to keep track of opened info window to not continue "animation" when user closes it during these 2 seconds.