# Google map OnInfoWindowClickListener slide animation

Tags: android, google-maps, animation, infowindow

I want to show a slide animation when user click in the google map info window.

My animation is work correclty, showing and dissapearing, but when i click to dissapear, the google map freezes and dont work anymore, but the app dont get a force close, and the menu still work. if i click in the menu, go to another activity and then get back, the map works again,if i click on info window to show the animation its freeze again.

```
   googlemap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(final Marker marker) {
                Animation animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slidedown);
                layoutToAdd.addView(view);
                view.startAnimation(animation1);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "animation opened", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if ( view != null) {
                    layoutToAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if (view.isShown()) {
                                Animation animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slideup);
                                view.startAnimation(animation1);
                                ((LinearLayout) view.getParent()).removeView(view);
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "animation closed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class= "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        >
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainlo"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

</LinearLayout>
</fragment>




    <!-- Side navigation drawer UI -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navList"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:background="#ffeeeeee"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

EDIT:
xml to call the animation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/lay">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mytext"
            android:text="You inflated me..i added to u r layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The animation.

Slide Down

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />
</set>
```

Slide Up

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.0" />

</set>
```

any help is apreciate.

Thanks

Comment: In general, it seems working with animation on infowindow or attaching view might cause lagging. Here's a related issue. Hope this gives you some ideas: [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164278/animated-infowindow-in-google-maps-v2)

Comment: this animation it is not to the infowindow...the animation appears when users click on the infowindow from google map...when click on infowindow, it calls an another xml with linearlayout(look my code edited)...the problem is the googlemap freeze when close this linearlayout

Comment: did you fix this issue?

Comment: I did a work around to fix this

Answer (score 0):

> An info window is not a live View, rather the view is rendered as an image onto the map. As a result, any listeners you set on the view are disregarded and you cannot distinguish between click events on various parts of the view. You are advised not to place interactive components — such as buttons, checkboxes, or text inputs — within your custom info window.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows